# Одна всплывающая форма по нескольким кнопкам

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

У меня на сайте есть много кнопок. И одна форма обратной связи, которая должна всплывать по нажатию любой из них. Как это грамотнее всего реализовать?
Сайт на bootstrap-3, хотя я не думаю, что это имеет значение

Код формы

```
  <form>
       <input type="text">
       <input type="text">
       <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
```

Код кнопки

```
<a class="btn btn-success services col-xs-12 hidden-sm-up" href="#">Заказать</a>
```

И в одно из полей `input` должно заноситься значение заголовка `h4`, предшествующего кнопке.

Comment: В чем вопрос? В бутстрапе есть готовые всплывающие окна. Вы документацию по нему читали?

Comment: На все кнопки ставьте один `onclick`

Comment: форма, которая должна всплывать - это модальное окно? Имеется ли значение, какая кнопка была нажата? Нужно что-то передавать? Добавьте код в свой вопрос: форму и пару кнопок, чтобы основываясь на Вашем коде - дать ответ.

Answer (score 0):

нужно повесить на все кнопки один класс , или сделать кнопки с которых вызывается эта форма одного класса , или задать какои то другой атрибут,  не требующий уникального значения  , по клику на кнопку с классом или каким то другим атрибутом  - открытие вашей формы . Форме соответственно задать айди .

Answer (score 0):

Пффф.. Это и без `bootstrap` прекрасно решается:

Пример со вспыхивающим окном:

```js
$("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
  var currentValue = $(this).val();
  $("#keeper").val(currentValue);
});

$(".btn").click(function(){
  if($("#keeper").val().length < 1){
    $("#error").text("Выберите продукт!");
    return false;}
  else {$(".popup").fadeIn(700);
        $(".content h3 b").text($("#keeper").val());}
});

$(".underlay").click(function(){
  $(".popup").fadeOut(700);
});
```

```css
h4 {display: inline-block;}

a {text-decoration: none; color: darkgreen; padding: 3px; background-color: violet; width: 30px; border: 2px outset;}

section.popup {display: none; position: fixed;
width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 3;}
div.underlay {background-color: black; opacity: 0.69;
position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0;
left: 0; z-index: 3;}
div.content {width: 100%; z-index: 4; position: fixed; height: 40%;}
div.content form {width: 70%; margin: 0;
position: relative;background-color: #6C4E74;
height: 100%; left: 50%; margin-left: -35%;}
div.content form input {display: block; width: 70%; border: 2px inset silver; margin: 10px auto;}
div.content form input:fisrt-of-type {margin-top: 15px;}
div.content form button {display: block; width: 30%; float: right; margin-right: 15%; border: 2px outset grey; background-color: silver; color: yellow;}
#error {color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4><input type="radio" value="футболку"/>Футболка</h4>
<h4><input type="radio" value="кепку"/>Кепка</h4>
<h4><input type="radio" value="куртку"/>Куртка</h4>
<h4><input type="radio" value="кроссовки"/>Кроссовки</h4>
<br/>

<input type="hidden" value="" id="keeper"/>

<a class="btn btn-success services col-xs-12 hidden-sm-up" href="javascript:void(0)">Заказать</a>
<span id="error"></span><br/><br/>
<a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)">Бла-бла-бла что-то еще но тот же класс</a><br/><br/>
<a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)">Еще одна</a><br/><br/>
<a class="btn" href="javascript:void(0)">И последняя</a><br/><br/>

<section class="popup">
<div class="underlay"></div>
<div class="content">
 <form>
 <h3>Купить <b></b></h3>
       <input type="text">
       <input type="text">
       <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
    </form>
</div>
</section>
```

С `css` уже сами шаманьте.

Answer (score 0):

Повесить событие клика на контейнер в котором все эти кнопки, будь то враппер или документ. Например:

```js
var popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if(event.target.dataset.type == 'popup') {
    event.preventDefault();
    popup.style.display = 'block';
    var form = popup.querySelector('form');
    form.special.value = event.target.previousElementSibling.innerText;
    console.log(form.special.value);
  }
})
```

```css
.popup{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<h4>text</h4>
<a data-type="popup" href="#">кнопка</a>
<div class="popup">
  <form action="" method="">
    <p>form</p>
    <input name="special" type="hidden">
    <input name="data" type="text" 
  </form>
</div>
```

Это самый простой вариант без стилей, дополнительных проверок и т.п. Главное суть......